# How to generate an error when important input text boxes are empty

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am creating a data entry userform that calculates loads (e.g.pipeloads, wind loads etc..). There are important text boxes that cannot be left unfilled. If the user clicks the command "Add Input" and there are some text boxes left unfilled, I want an error to be generated that forces the user to enter a value.

I've got as far as generating an error for one text box. This code will trigger an error alert when you try to leave the text box without filling it first.

```
    Private Sub txtdist_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Trim(txtdist.Value) = "" And Me.Visible Then
    MsgBox "Required Entry!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Cancel = True
    txtdist.BackColor = vbRed
    Else
    txtdist.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
    End If
    End Sub
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I click "Continue" command button, then the program will see if any textbox or combobox is left empty to force the user to enter a value. (Similar to when you try to buy online with credit card, the page will not submit if there is not name or credit card number etc...). Thank you.

Comment: You could use data validation to force the user to enter a value?  [data validation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249)

Comment: You could decide on the tab order, disable all but the first control, and then progressively enable them as the fields are filled in. Basically force them to do what you want, rather than check up on them after the fact. On the other hand, this might annoy users who would prefer a different order of data entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
Private Sub Continue_click()

Dim c as Control

    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then

            If Trim(c.Value) = "" Then
              MsgBox "Please fill out all required information", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
            End If

        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: This work real well. Thank you so much! I will try to understand every line of this code. I've tried it and it works! Formally accepting these lines of codes to answer my question. @Dorian and Louis

Comment: @JovicViduya [Click here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) . Once you accepted this your issue will be set as solved, this will help other people having quite the same need than yours. 

Kindest regards

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the code to check for empty textboxes when you click "Continue" `Command Button`, you should add your check code in that `Sub`.

Here's an example on how you can do it:

```
Sub Continue_click()
    '...

    If Trim(txtdist.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill out all required information", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '...
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that this is what he already have `If Trim(txtdist.Value) = "" And Me.Visible Then`

Comment: @Louis Your code actually works well. Thank you. But I have 12 text boxes and 1 combobox that need to filled out. How do I do that with a sort of loop so I don't have to put this error in all 12 text boxes? Thank you!

Comment: @Dorian yes, but in the wrong Sub. He needs to add that code in the `Continue` Button.

Comment: @JovicViduya Since you have many controls, you can combine my solution and @Dorian one. Put the check in the `Continue` Button and then use a similar `For` Loop like the one showed.